# Joomla Warning Showing Incorrect PHP Version

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, installation, migration, error-handling

Using Joomla 3.9.8

I recently migrated from localhost (PHP 7.1.9) to a live server (PHP 7.2)

On localhost my site was installed at `localhost/mysote`. On my live server it's installed at `dev.example.com/mysite`

When I view my site on the live server I see the following notice;

> **Error** We have detected that your server is using PHP 5.6.37 which is
>   obsolete and no longer receives official security updates by its
>   developers. The Joomla! Project recommends upgrading your site to PHP
>   7.1 or later which will receive security updates at least until 2019-12-01. Please ask your host to make PHP 7.1 or a later version
>   the default version for your site. If your host is already PHP 7.1
>   ready please enable PHP 7.1 on your site's root and 'administrator'
>   directories – typically you can do this yourself through a tool in
>   your hosting control panel, but it's best to ask your host if you are
>   unsure.

Does the fact that the site is installed on a subdomain make any difference?

I have a site installed at `example.com` and it's working fine, no PHP errors.

I had a look at the `.htaccess` on the subdomain and there's no mention of a PHP version, so it's not set manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing Joomla in a subdomain should make no difference as far as the PHP version is concerned.

The likely explanation is that there is a directive in the `.htaccess` file overriding the default PHP version but you have already checked this.

To fault find this issue, I recommend:

1. Creating a `phpinfo.php` file in the root folder of the subdomain and browsing to the file to check what PHP version is reported. Your `phpinfo.php` file should contain:

   `<?php
     phpinfo();
   ?>`

   Remember to delete the file after use.
2. In Global Configuration, temporarily disable URL Rewriting and then temporarily rename your `.htaccess` file to `htaccess.disabled` or similar. If the warning message disappears, then you may need to take a closer look at the `.htaccess` file.